# How to use If/Else or Case statement for a checkbox with in a Select Query in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, checkbox, case

I have a check box on front end.

If the check box is checked: data with only checked chk1 should appear on front end.

If the check box is not checked: full data should appear on front end.

Please suggest how should I proceed with the same in SQL Using If else / Case statement.

I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
where (some conditions) AND
    CASE @a.Id_Oem_Irm
        WHEN 0 THEN (a.id_oem_irm in(0,1))
        WHEN 1 THEN (a.id_oem_irm in (1))
    END
```

PS: a.Id_Oem_Irm: a is the table name, Id_oem_irm is the column name for check box.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
where (some conditions) AND
      ((@a.Id_Oem_Irm = 0 and a.id_oem_irm in(0, 1)) OR
       (@a.Id_Oem_Irm = 1 and a.id_oem_irm in (1) )
      )
```

I am not sure what `@a.Id_Oem_Irm` is supposed to be.  I suspect you want a variable there.

Comment: a is the table name and Id_Oem_irm is the column in that table which represents value of check box

Answer (score 0):

Or you could tune it a bit like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
where (some conditions) AND
    (a.id_oem_irm = 1 OR
    @a.Id_Oem_Irm = 0)
```

This is only valid if `@a.Id_Oem_Irm` is always 0 or 1. Otherwise, you obviously should add a `@a.Id_Oem_Irm IN (0,1)` or `<= 1` (if it can't be negative) condition.

What is `a`? The alias for another table you didn't include here?

Comment: Yes, a is the alias name of one table. Id_Oem_irm shall have either 0 or 1 value.. if check box is checked, it will have 1 value & if it is un checked it will have 0 value.

Comment: Please note I simplified it a bit more. Does this work for you?

Comment: Getting error : Must declare the scalar variable "@a".

Comment: That `@a` was in your code... If you don't know what it is, nobody does. :P Where do you receive the checkbox value?

Answer (score -1):

The simpler way to do this is create a storedprocedure which will take the input "@a.Id_Oem_Irm"

### Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_get_a_data(
IN Id INT(1)
)
BEGIN
  IF (Id = 0) BEGIN
     --YOur query to retrieve partiular row/ column
  END;

  IF(Id = 1) BEGIN
    --YOur query to retrieve all data
     SELECT * FROM table1
        where (some conditions)
  END;

END
```

The usage of stored procedure will give you selected data and the query is precompiled in the database so it faster.

Note: I didn't quite understand what your query is returning so replace mine with yours

Comment: I added the formatting and fixed your code, which was more like C# rather than SQL. However, a SP is out of the scope of the question; his script may already be in one. :P Duplicating the script is a bad practice when a single query will more than suffice.

Comment: Creating stored procedure gives flexibility and understandability to a new person